# how can i calculate the sum of a column in a dynamically newly added row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sum, html-table

I am newbie in javascript and cakephp. I have added a new row using javascript and now I want to calculate the sum of the column "amount" whenever I fill the amount field.
HTML code for adding new field :

```
<table id="voucher_line"  style="width:750px; font-size:13px;">
<tr>
    <th>Others Component</th>
    <th>Others GoB</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<tr id="voucher_">
    <td style="width:150px;"><?php echo $this->Form->input('DebitVoucherLine.0.coa_component_id',array('options'=>$coa_components,'type'=>'select','label'=>false));?></td>

    <td style="width:150px;"><?php echo $this->Form->input('DebitVoucherLine.0.level_five_id',array('type'=>'select','label'=>false));?></td>

    <td style="width:204px;"><?php echo $this->Form->input('DebitVoucherLine.0.amount', array('label'=>false, 'type'=>'text'));?></td>
</tr>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(":button#add").click(function() {
var clonedRow = $("#voucher_line tr:last").clone();
var newIndex = (document.getElementById('voucher_line').rows.length-1);

clonedRow[0].id = 'voucher_' + newIndex;
$.each($('input, select', clonedRow), function(i, val){
    val.name = val.name.replace((newIndex - 1), newIndex);
    val.id = val.id.replace((newIndex - 1), newIndex);
    val.value = '';
})
$("#voucher_line").append(clonedRow); 
});

$(":button#remove").click(function(){ 
if ($("#voucher_line tr").length != 2) {
 $("#voucher_line tr:last").remove();
}   
});

</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this sounds more like a javascript question. You probably want to calculate the value in javascript

Comment: This has nothing to do with php at all, please use the correct tags and don't throw the cakephp tag in every question. I've been editing tags for ~10 days in different questions, this has really become a bad habit of many people.

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate over all lines in the table and calculate the value.  Here's a quick example:

```
function calculateTableTotal() {
  var total = 0;

  $('#voucher_line tr td input[type="text"]').each(function() {

    // find the amount input field
    var $input = $(this);
    total += parseInt($input.val());
  });

  alert('The total is : ' + total);

}
```

Comment: Thanks Filype..it works great :) 
Can you give me any idea on how i can show the total in an input field ?

Comment: that's pretty straight forward: say you have an input with an id `total` the following lines would do it `$('#total').val(total);`

Comment: The delete option is not deleting data from database...can you help me how to do it ? 
Thanks in advance.